# How would I round a binary number to significant figures?

Tags: binary, rounding

I was given a problem of converting

```
1203.201 which is 0100|1011|0011.0011|0011
```

into binary, but I'm also supposed to round the binary representation to 6 significant figures and 12 significant figures. But wouldn't changing any digit in the 0's and 1's make a new number? So, what am I supposed to?

Comment: 6 significant binary digits, or 6 significant *decimal* digits?

Comment: 6 significant binary digits

Comment: Right, so that's `0100|11000|0000.0000|0000`. Yes, that will change the decimal representation, but that's just what happens...

Comment: Oh... that simple, huh?
It makes sense now, there weren't any examples in the book nor could I find one online.